# iPhone settings: create dependent settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, application-settings

Is it possible to create "dependent settings"? e.g. you have hierarchical settings like this:

```
 - include animals
 -- include dogs
 -- include cats
```

where toggling animals would automatically toggle dogs and cats (I know I can cater for that in code, but can the settings screen that is provided by the OS be configured so the UISwitch for dogs is automatically set to off if include animals is set to off?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll either need to change your UI so this toggle is not required, display both options and hope it doesn't confuse your users or only include the settings inside your app where you can write the correct code yourself.

This is a really annoying limitation. It's probably worth raising a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I was afraid so. I am probably going to do an in-app settings screen anyways but still...